# How I use get method with variables in flutter http?

Tags: api, flutter, http, flutter-http

[image: Error Image Here]

I want to call API but I can't give latitude and longitude as variables.

Comment: in the future post code snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you would want to define your uri in the `getData` method.
example:

```
getData({String latitude,String longitude})async{
..define uri. var url =Uri.https..
http.Response..
```

Answer (score 0):

As griffin said to write url in getData function, so do that and also Extract and pass the query parameters like this in that function

```
void getData(double latitude,double longitude) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> param = {
          'longitude': longitude,
          'latitude': latitude,
        };

    var url = Uri.https('api/openweathermap.org',
        '/data/2.5/weather',
        param);
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function instead of variable

```
Uri url(double latitude, double longitude) {
    return Uri.https('api.abc.org', 'data/123/abc', {
      'lat': latitude,
      'lon': longitude,
    });
  }

Future<void> getData(double latitude, double longitude) async {
  final response = await http.get(url(latitude, longitude));
}
```